# Updating mongodb in a mean stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I want to update my mongodb I know what to write on the server side but i dont know how to use it on the client side in angular. can you help ? 
here is my server side code

```
module.exports.updateUser = function (req, res) {
// get a user with ID of 1
User.findById(1, function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // change the users location
  user.location = 'uk';

  // save the user
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('User successfully updated!');
  });

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a rest api(/users/save)

```
 var users =  require('./src/servies/users');
    app.post('/users/save', users.updateUser);
```

that will call your updateUser function.
In angular you can use http module something like below code

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("HttpPostController", function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.SendData = function () {
           // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON 
            var data = $.param({
                location: $scope.location
            });

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }
            // calling post /users/save api from angular code 
            $http.post('/users/save', data, config)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {

            });
        };

    });
</script>
```

Comment: 10q for your response. can you explain what does the script ?

Comment: In script tag i created an angular app module within that i am calling a http rest api call (/users/save)

Comment: Whats the use of $scope.SendData and how do i pass parameters like the id

Comment: it's a function that will be call from html page. when you call the method from html page you can send the required values in that method